# Spring Email Form Validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am about to setup form validation in `Spring 3.1`. I am using Annotations to validate my Model, like this:

Model:

```
@Column(name = "mailAddress", nullable = false)
@Email
private String mailAddress;

@Column(name = "school", nullable = false)
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 3, max = 100)
private String school;
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBooking(
            @ModelAttribute("new-booking") @Valid Booking booking,
            BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "booking";
        }
            return "success";
     }
```

The Problem is, it validates the `school` but not the `mailAddress`. If you enter an empty `mailAddress` it will accept it.

Comment: @VarunAchar You are totally right. It seems I just forgot about that. Edited.

Comment: What is the input to mailAddress? Is it validating it for every case or failing for every case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the Issue. The Email Validator will accept Blank Emails. To fix this you only need to add a `@NotBlank` to it. Actually I thought the nullable = false would be enought, but wasn't.

```
@Column(name = "mailAddress", nullable = false)
@Email
@NotBlank
private String mailAddress;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that maybe your validation problem could be related to the fact that using @Email validation annotation your validator cosindered as valid also e-mail having form like: "myname@service" that don't end with an extension like (for example) .com

If this is your problem...this is normal because it considered also the case that you have an e-mail having the following format: yourname@localhost (internal email address)

If you would validate a classic e-mail (having format: myname@someservice.com) I think that you have to write your custom validator.

I hope that I have understand your problem

Comment: Thank you, but it won't validate the Email at all. I can leave it blank and nothing the Controller accepts this.